# ToogleSwitch don't have theme color

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I inserted a toogleswitch on a WindowsPhone 7.1 programm, and i would like to this control takes the theme color ( like the "Alarm" programm on Windows Phone).

Actually, my toggleSwitch is like this :

[image]

and i would this ( like my theme ) :

[image]

Here is my XAML code :

```
    <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Margin="193,371,0,0" Name="toggleSwitch1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" Height="114" />
```

Have you an idea ? I have tired several tips but no changes :(

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

EDIT :

I have tried this, but no changes

```
    <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Margin="193,371,0,0" Name="toggleSwitch1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" Height="114" Header="{Binding Path=LocalisedResources.Show24HourText}">
        <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
    </toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use HeaderTemplate to ensure that foreground is in Accent color try

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch Name="btnShow24Hrs" IsChecked="true" Click="btnShow24Hrs_Click" Header="{Binding Path=LocalisedResources.Show24HourText}">
    <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
</toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
```

Comment: Thanks, if i paste your code, it create a new ToggleSwitch, but if I modofy the mine, i see no changes :(

Comment: I have edit my question with my example using your tips, could you help me please ? I see no changes. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: if you directly paste my xaml and change the header value to Header="something" does it correctly show the accent ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was due to the current HTC theme !!